# How to calculate (hh:mm:ss + minutes()) and show the all result in MATLAB GUI table?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, time

```
for i = 1:10
    result(i, 2) = duration('08:00:00') + minutes(result(i,2))
end
set(handles.uitable1, 'data', result)
```

---

Then, I will show result which is global variable into GUI table. How can I show it in GUI table?
Normally, I use minutes to calculate but I want to show the exact time (hh:m:ss) in GUI table. I, now, show the minutes at GUI table as below. Below figure link shows result at GUI table. I need to convert it to hh:mm:ss with above for-loop.
Result contains numbers like 40, 68, 93.  I use them as minutes.

With above code, I get this error:

```
The following error occurred converting from duration to double:    
Undefined function 'double' for input arguments of type 'duration'. To convert from durations to numeric, use the SECONDS, MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS, or YEARS functions.
Error in Optprog>pushbutton4_Callback (line 290)
    result(i,2) = duration('08:00:00') + minutes(result(i,2))

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in Optprog (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)Optprog('pushbutton4_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

Error while evaluating UIControl Callback.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is, you are converting the previous results to minutes, but then you add a duration:

```
result(i, 2) = duration('08:00:00') + minutes(result(i,2))
```

The result of a duration and double is a duration. You want double. Try this:

```
result(i, 2) = minutes(duration('08:00:00') + result(i,2))
```

First add, then convert to double.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I need to transfer it by hh:mm:ss format. For example, by making hand-calculation, I get 60 as minute in result(1,2), then I adding it to the 08:00:00 and I find it as 09:00:00.  
with above code, I get 86880 at GUI table instead of 09:00:00 in hh:mm:ss format.

Comment: Okay, I looked only at the error message, assuming you want a double. Guess to display a 09:00:00 you have to input a character array. You can use `char` for the conversion. Probably your original code and `set(handles.uitable1, 'data', char(result))`. Without a complete example, I can't try it.

Comment: I get this error; Error using matlab.ui.control.Table/set
Error setting property 'Data' of class 'Table':
Data must be a numeric, logical, string, cell, or table array. I can try to make a sample code to share here, thanks.